# jQuery: of current element, get the parent ".radioGroup" and select each radio

Tags: jquery

Subject pretty much says it all...

What I need to do is change the style of all of the radio buttons within the current elements group.

```
$(element).closest(".radioGroup").("input:radio").each(function(i, target) {
    // change css
});
```

close, but no cigar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you forgot the find method :)

```
$(element).closest(".radioGroup").find("input:radio").each(function(i, target) {
    // change css
});
```

Comment: DOH! So it seems! Thank you, FRAGA!